# SQL Server query poor performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, query-performance, sqlperformance

We are working with an app, .NET, in which when you press a button a DevExpress form is opened and a SQL Server query is executed, so it can fill with data some comboboxes. Application is working fine in lots of customers, but in a particular one it´s taking more than a minute in loading the form. I can see in the performance monitor that SQL Server is taking a lot of CPU when I want to load the form.

I executed the query directly in SQL Server Management Studio, taking no more than a second, however I tried having a look at SQL Activity Monitor and what I can see here (not happening to other customers, same IO, same SQL, same everything) is this:

[image]

So the thing I can see here, that I don´t understand, is why is this query having so much executions? Why is it taking so long to retrieve data?
Here it´s the execution plan of this query:

```
Select * 
From cuinac_pos  
Where [group] in (Select [group] 
                  From proc_groups  
                  Where Code = 13100271)
```

[image]

Thank you for any help you can give me, and please if I can give any more info do not hesitate to ask.

Once again, thanks!

AFTER ADDING THE EXECUTION PLAN SUGGESTED INDEX

[image]

[image]

EXECUTION PLAN FOR QUERY

```
Select count(*) 
From proc_groups 
Where Code = 13100271
```

[image]

[image]

Definition of the index in proc_groups:

[image]

Example of the code:

```
private static void LoadDTPurchaseHerdRelation(Int32 status, Int32 herdNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                sb.Append(" Select gr.[group] as HerdId, gr.code as HerdNumber, bo.code as PurchaseCode");
                sb.Append(" From cuinac_pos bo ");
                sb.Append(" inner join proc_groups gr on bo.code=gr.code ");

                if (herdNumber == 0)
                {
                    string s1 = " Where (gr.created between '2015-12-09' And '2016-01-08') ";
                    sb.Append(s1);

                    if (status != 4)
                    {
                        string s2 = string.Format(" AND bo.purchasestatus = {0} ", status);
                        sb.Append(s2);
                    }

                    sb.Append(" order by bo.code ");
                }
                else
                {
                    string s3 = string.Format(" Where gr.code = '{0}' ", herdNumber);
                    sb.Append(s3);
                }

                DTPurchaseHerdRelation.Clear();
                using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), (SqlConnection)cs.Connection);
                    adapter.Fill(DTPurchaseHerdRelation);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Execution plan for query

Select * From cuinac_pos Where [group] in (Select [group] From proc_groups Where Code = N'13100271')

[image]

Solved:

I finally got it by adding indexes suggested in the answer marked as correct, and adding in the code, in the queries which searched by nvarchar value "Code", an N before rhe value as suggested in comments by shriop. Thank you all for your effort!

Comment: In the 2nd screenshot, isn't it asking you to create an index on the cuinac_pos.group column?

Comment: right click on the execution plan and pick missing index. this will give you index script. then try it again

Comment: I built the suggested index as the Execution plan, with no success.

Comment: I HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION WITH IMAGES AFETER INDEX GENERATION

Comment: I need several pieces of info to help. Select count(*) From proc_groups  Where Code = 13100271. Select count(*) From proc_groups. What data type is Code? What is the execution plan for Select count(*) From proc_groups  Where Code = 13100271? Fixing the plan for that simpler query is the next problem to get it to not "index scan".

Comment: And are you sure you don't have a loop in your code that calls this multiple times for one page?

Comment: @shriop the result for first select is 1, and for second select is 17401. Code is a nvarchar(30) . I will edit question and add execution plan that you ascked for. Thank you a lot

Comment: You will probably need to add an additional part of the execution plan, that  has the properties of the hover over the index scan. There's got to be some data type conversion or something going on there that's causing the index scan. There's no reason for it to be index scanning when there is only a single row in the table that matches the filter.

Comment: @shriop Thank you. Sorry for my ignorance, can you help me a little bit more? What do you mean to add an aditional part? I have to create something or are u just needing more info from me?

Comment: I just need more info. If you hover over the Index Scan, there will be a popup with additional values that I'm hoping shows the reason why the database is choosing to Index Scan over such a simple single row query. There might be an implicit data type conversion or something. Also, can you give the exact definition of the ix_proc_groups_code index as you have it now? You might not have created it correctly.

Comment: What's your app code look like? Is it LINQ or is it just submitting SQL directly? Since the issue only appears in the app, "SQL Server Management Studio, taking no more than a second", indexes aren't the problem. There are two code smells  that query: 1. using `select *`, 2. using `IN (select group....)` As mentioned below, try running your query in SSMS with `SET ARITHABORT OFF` beforehand. Long story behind this but try and see if that reporduces your performance issue in SSMS first.

Comment: @shriop Ok, I will add hover screenshot in the index scan you told me, and the properties definition for the index created. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hi, thanks for your interest. I will edit the question and add an example of the code. As I said, I tried running the query in SSMS and takes no more than a second, but when executed through the app, it takes too long. However, I checked activity monitor in SSMS and Windows Performance, and seems to be SQL stuff

Comment: What does Select * 
From cuinac_pos  
Where [group] in (Select [group] 
                  From proc_groups  
                  Where Code = N'13100271') look like in the execution plan? Code is an NVARCHAR.

Comment: @shriop you mean you need the index scan and the index seek hover in the execution plan?

Comment: No. Run "Select * From cuinac_pos Where [group] in (Select [group] From proc_groups Where Code = N'13100271')" and show the execution plan. I think it's going to show an "index seek" instead of an "index scan". And if so, you'll need to alter your C# accordingly. string s3 = string.Format(" Where gr.code = N'{0}' ", herdNumber); Then see if your application runs faster.

Comment: @shriop You are right. Execution plan for this query is already attached in my question. What will this change in the code do exactly?

Comment: I changed the query, so no, I do not see an execution plan above nor the changed query. "Select * From cuinac_pos Where [group] in (Select [group] From proc_groups Where Code = N'13100271')". The key piece is running it inside single quotes, and prefixing the single quotes with the letter N. This defines it as an NVARCHAR value. If you look at the screenshot of the hover that you provided, it shows a CONVERT_IMPLICIT that is preventing the index from being used. Making the change in the query and the code is an attempt to remove that.

Comment: @shriop Sorry, i will add execution plan in for this query in the question as requested.

Comment: So how many records does this query actually return? Does the problem client have a lot of records? When trying to reproduce the issue in SSMS (which hasn't been achieved yet), I suggest you use SQL Profiler to capture the query **including** all the `SET` parts at the start (particularly noting the `SET ARITHABORT` part). Once you reproduce the issue in SSMS, you can more easily solve it.

Comment: I solved it @shriop, thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
Select *
From cuinac_pos
Where [group] in (Select [group] From proc_groups  Where Code = 13100271 );
```

The optimal indexes are `proc_groups(code, group)` and `cuinac_pos(group)`.  Having those indexes might help.

EDIT:

For performance, this might be better:

```
Select *
From cuinac_pos cp
Where exists (Select 1
              From proc_groups pg
              Where pg.Code = 13100271 and pg.[group] = cp.[group]
             );
```

with an index on `proc_groups(group, code)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have added the index suggested in the execution plan, but still it´s very very slow.

Comment: Modifying the code is our last option, cause it´s working in all the clients except this one, by the moment we are going to try making changes in SQL. However, thanks for the advice, maybe we will have to make some modifications in the code at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I read something like "fast in SSMS but slow in application" I have to think about this:

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

This applies especially to older DBs, which exist from SQL Server version to SQL Server version and are upgraded via scripts, and where the data reading is done through Stored Procedures.

Most of the time this behaviour is solveable with a `SET ARITHABORT ON` as first line of your SQL code.

You can put this into you SPs directly, or set it in your application through the Connection as default.